# Strange project structure after running gradle in new Mobile Android/iOS project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm new to mobile dev so this might be a dumb question.

I expect the src directory to contain the following folders:

- commonMain
- commanTest
- iosMain
- iosTest
- main
- test

But after running gradle sync I get the following structure, which does not seem correct:

- androidAndroidTest
- androidAndroidTestDebug
- androidDebug
- androidDebugAndroidTest
- androidDebugUnitTest
- androidMain
- androidRelease
- androidReleaseUnitTest
- androidTest
- androidTestDebug
- androidTestRelease
- commonMain
- commanTest
- debug
- iosMain
- iosTest
- main
- release
- test
- testDebug
- testRelease
- test

Comment: Can you extend the question with the Gradle script contents? This can be really important here.

Comment: Sounds like this issue with Kotlin Gradle Android integration: [KT-34127](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34127).